# Inner join multiple tables get name instead of id

Tags: mysql

I have 4 tables

```
Table incidences-employees
---------------------------
idIncidenceEmployee PK
idEmployee FK (employee.idemployee)
idMasterIncidence FK (incidence-master.idIncidence)
createdby FK (user-employee.idMongoUser)
authorizedBy FK (user-employee.idMongoUser)

Table incidence-master
---------------------------
idIncidence PK
name

TAble user-employee
--------------------------
idMongoUser PK
idEmployee

Table EMployee
-------------------------
idEmployee Pk
name
lastName
```

I do this query

```
SELECT employee.name, incidences-master.name, incidences-employees.* 
  FROM employee-incidences 
    INNER JOIN employee ON employee.idEmployee = employee-incidences.idEmployee 
    INNER JOIN incidences-master ON incidences-master.idIncidence = employee-incidences.idIncidenceEmployee
```

I get this

```
Employee name | Incidence name | idIncidenceEmployee | idEmployee | idMasterIncidence | createdby | authorizedBy 
John Doe      | Incidence Name |               1     |    1       |                 5 |    abc123 | abc123
```

But on created and authorizated by I get an ID, abc123, what I want is to match the id with a name, that id is ont the table user-employee

```
    Table user-employee          Table Employee
   ----------------------    -   -------------------
    idMongoUser -> abc123        idEmployee -> 1
    idemployee -> 1              Name -> John Doe
```

I want John Doe to appear instead of the id.

Answer (score 0):

incidences-employees.* is giving you all the fields from that table, which include the two IDs.  One approach is to do two more joins, joining the employee table to the incidences table where employee.idemployee = incidences-employee.createdby and authorizedby.

Then instead of using .*, you reference each field you want.  You will also make things easier by using aliases like:

```
select ... from incidences-employee I
join employee E1 on E1.idemployee = I.createdby
```

Then you can reference E1.name for the createdby name.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this:

```
SELECT employee.name as employeeName, incidences-master.name as incidenceName, e1.name as createdBy, e2.name as authorisedBy
FROM employee-incidences 
INNER JOIN incidences-master ON incidences-master.idIncidence = employee-incidences.idIncidenceEmployee
INNER JOIN employee ON employee.idEmployee = employee-incidences.idEmployee
INNER JOIN user-employee ue1 on ue1.idMongoUser = employee-incidences.createdBy
INNER JOIN employee e1 on e1.idEmployee = ue1.idEmployee
INNER JOIN user-employee ue2 on ue2.idMongoUser = employee-incidences.AuthorizedBy
INNER JOIN employee e2 on e2.idEmployee = ue2.idEmployee
```

If there were cases where createdBy or authorisedBy could be empty or null, then I'd suggest to use Left Joins instead of Inner Joins

Comment: Jayvee, if you're going to essentially mirror a previous answer, it would be nice to at least acknowledge it.  I took the approach of leading him to the way to solve it rather than handing him the entire query.  Neither of our approaches is more right or wrong...still...be mindful of that.  Thanks.

Comment: I think the main difference in our approaches is that there is a junction table (user-employee) that you are not using or suggesting to use in your answer.

Comment: In this part `e1.name as createdBy, e2.name`, how does mysql knows what table are you referring to?, as opposed to `incidences-master.name`, where we explicitly say the table name

Comment: that's because I'm using aliases on the join because I'm joining 3 times to employees, for employee, createdby and authorisedby respectively

Comment: Sebastian, look up how table aliases work.  It will save you a lot of typing and make your queries much more readable.